# Literals are objects in python?

Tags: python

I am from Java programming, new to Python. Should I consider integer, float and string literals also as object of python programming?

eg: `2`, `4.3`, `'stackoveflow'`

Comment: I would recommend reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before asking a question. This is very unclear

Comment: Can you explain your question? What you mean by **object of python programming**

Answer (score 3):

[Everything in python is an object.](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) Even functions and plain numbers/booleans.

> *Objects* are Python’s abstraction for data. All data in a Python program is represented by objects

This has quite some advantages, for example, you can easily subclass a type such as `str` or `unicode` if you need a custom type with the default behaviour but additional features (often done in template engines to mark strings as HTML-safe).
Another more common thing is the `join()` method on strings. While most languages have such a methods on arrays, Python has it as a string method which is used like this, allowing you to pass *any* iterable/sequence to it: `', '.join(some_iterable)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every value is an object in Python. For example:

```
>>> dir(3)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__ceil__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__floor__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__index__', '__init__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__round__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'from_bytes', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real', 'to_bytes']
>>> (3).__str__()
'3'
```

Answer (score 1):

[Every value is an object in Python](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types). `42`, `"stackoverflow"`, and `(1,)` are all objects and have a [type](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type):

```
>>> (42).bit_length() # parentheses necessary for syntactic reasons
6
>>> "stackoverflow".upper()
'STACKOVERFLOW'
>>> type((1,))
<type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: @user1335578 Instead (or in addition to) saying Thank you, aou could start to accept answers. It will give you points as well!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact, doing so is central to some common idioms - especially string formatting:

```
>>> "Hello {}".format("name")
'Hello name'
```

and joining the items of a sequence:

```
>>> a = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> ' + '.join(a)
'one + two + three'
```

Both of these rely on string literals being objects, and hence being able to call methods on them.